# Rendering pweave pmd with python module

Tags: python, pweave

I have a python code that generates a report in `.pmd` format, and then renders it as an html with this command:

```
import subprocess
cmd_pweave = "pweave -f md2html file.pmd"
subprocess.run(cmd_pweave, shell=True, check=True)
```

I want to avoid calling the terminal, because that can be a problem with integrability with windows (right now I'm using a mac).

So the question is: is there a way to render this pmd file to html with the python pweave library?
I've looked through the doc, but I can't find how to do it.

It should be something like:

```
import pweave
# Weave a pandoc document with default options
pweave.weave('file.pmd')
```

Python pweave module doc is here http://mpastell.com/pweave/pweave.html#simple-weaving-and-tangling
and an example in pmd is here: http://mpastell.com/pweave/_downloads/FIR_designp.pmd

Any help is appreciated

UPDATE:
here is the traceback

````
  File "/Applications/miniconda3/envs/ptools/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3326, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-6-32aca0d5d946>", line 2, in <module>
    pweave.weave("path with spaces/dt_2020_04_19__19_51_11/ptools_analysis_2020_04_19__19_51_11.pmd")
  File "/Applications/miniconda3/envs/ptools/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pweave/__init__.py", line 59, in weave
    doc.weave()
  File "/Applications/miniconda3/envs/ptools/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pweave/pweb.py", line 192, in weave
    self.run()
  File "/Applications/miniconda3/envs/ptools/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pweave/pweb.py", line 127, in run
    self.wd
  File "/Applications/miniconda3/envs/ptools/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pweave/processors/jupyter.py", line 169, in __init__
    super(IPythonProcessor, self).__init__(*args, embed_kernel=embed)
  File "/Applications/miniconda3/envs/ptools/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pweave/processors/jupyter.py", line 34, in __init__
    km.start_kernel(cwd=path, stderr=open(os.devnull, 'w'))
  File "/Applications/miniconda3/envs/ptools/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel/inprocess/manager.py", line 46, in start_kernel
    self.kernel = InProcessKernel(parent=self, session=self.session)
  File "/Applications/miniconda3/envs/ptools/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel/inprocess/ipkernel.py", line 72, in __init__
    super(InProcessKernel, self).__init__(**traits)
  File "/Applications/miniconda3/envs/ptools/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel/ipkernel.py", line 67, in __init__
    kernel      = self,
  File "/Applications/miniconda3/envs/ptools/lib/python3.7/site-packages/traitlets/config/configurable.py", line 423, in instance
    '%s are being created.' % cls.__name__
traitlets.config.configurable.MultipleInstanceError: Multiple incompatible subclass instances of InProcessInteractiveShell are being created.```
````

Comment: did not work for you `import pweave` and then `pweave.weave('file.pmd')` ?, what error are you getting?

Comment: Hi @elikesprogramming, I updated with the traceback, thanks!